# How do you include extra Python libraries on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I would like to include different Python libraries on my Mac, like numpy and other research libraries that aren't packaged by default with the Python installation. I should note that I installed the latest version of Python for mac from the official Python site. It installs in ~/Libraries/... rather than /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. Would I need to include those new libraries with my updated version? ie. In the same directory? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a virtualenv. E.g.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/science
source ~/.virtualenvs/science/bin/activate
pip install numpy scipy matplotlib ...
# work on your project
deactivate
```

`virtualenv` is a virtual enviornment for Python packages that avoids populating your default installation, besides other advantages. It is a standard in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I use [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) to install it's own python executable and additional libraries like scipy/numpy/matplotlib.

Another alternative is to use bundles, this discussion might be of interest [Anaconda vs. EPD Enthought vs. manual installation of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762943/anaconda-vs-epd-enthought-vs-manual-installation-of-python)