# Building Paraview from source with CMake and Python library linking issue

Tags: python, cmake, paraview

Building [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:Superbuild) from source in my VM (host windows7 guest Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS) using their latest Superbuild.

I do managed to compile the program without any issues, however, when importing `paraview.simple` in Anconda's `Python 2.7.11` I encounter the error `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2*`. When I used the compiled `pvpython` from the Paraview superbuild, which is using `Python 2.7.11` as well, I have no issues and can import `paraview.simple` without problems. A look to `sys.maxunicode>65535` outputs `False` only for the latter, meaning that my Anaconda python is using UCS4 whereas the compiled linked python libraries are using UC2.

Reading old threads and documentation, people have edited CMAKE options o point to the right libraries but such variables are not showing up in my `CMakeCache.txt` which I am including below for completeness:

```
//Enable shared libraries BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF

//Build the testing tree. BUILD_TESTING:BOOL=ON

//Enable to package prebuilt mesa binaries BUNDLE_PREBUILT_MESA_BINARIES:BOOL=OFF

//Path to a program. BZRCOMMAND:FILEPATH=BZRCOMMAND-NOTFOUND

//The catalyst edition to build CATALYST_EDITION:STRING=Essentials

//Enable Python support in catalyst CATALYST_PYTHON:BOOL=ON

//Path to a program. CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ar

//Choose the type of build, options are: None(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS or // CMAKE_C_FLAGS used) Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel. CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

//Enable/Disable color output during build. CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//CXX compiler CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types. CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds. CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds for minimum // size. CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds. CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds with debug info. CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//C compiler CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/cc

//Flags used by the compiler during all build types. CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the compiler during debug builds. CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds for minimum // size. CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds. CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the compiler during release builds with debug info. CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the linker. CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds. CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds. CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds. CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds. CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Enable/Disable output of compile commands during generation. CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=OFF

//Fortran compiler CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER:FILEPATH=NOTFOUND

//Fortran flags CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS:STRING=

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories. CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/paraview

//Path to a program. CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ld

//Path to a program. CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/make

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules. CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds. CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds. CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds. CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds. CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program. CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/nm

//Path to a program. CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objcopy

//Path to a program. CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objdump

//Value Computed by CMake CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=ParaViewSuperBuild

//Path to a program. CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ranlib

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of dll's. CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds. CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds. CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds. CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds. CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries, // but are added when building. CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries. CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries. CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during debug builds. CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release minsize builds. CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during release builds. CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during Release with Debug Info builds. CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program. CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/strip

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the // .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console // during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual // Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo. CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=FALSE

//Path to the coverage program that CTest uses for performing coverage // inspection COVERAGE_COMMAND:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcov

//Extra command line flags to pass to the coverage tool COVERAGE_EXTRA_FLAGS:STRING=-l

//Enable to build Debian packages CPACK_BINARY_DEB:BOOL=OFF

//Enable to build IFW packages CPACK_BINARY_IFW:BOOL=OFF

//Enable to build NSIS packages CPACK_BINARY_NSIS:BOOL=OFF

//Enable to build RPM packages CPACK_BINARY_RPM:BOOL=OFF

//Enable to build STGZ packages CPACK_BINARY_STGZ:BOOL=ON

//Enable to build TBZ2 packages CPACK_BINARY_TBZ2:BOOL=OFF

//Enable to build TGZ packages CPACK_BINARY_TGZ:BOOL=ON

//Enable to build TXZ packages CPACK_BINARY_TXZ:BOOL=OFF

//Enable to build TZ packages CPACK_BINARY_TZ:BOOL=ON

//Enable to build TBZ2 source packages CPACK_SOURCE_TBZ2:BOOL=ON

//Enable to build TGZ source packages CPACK_SOURCE_TGZ:BOOL=ON

//Enable to build TXZ source packages CPACK_SOURCE_TXZ:BOOL=ON

//Enable to build TZ source packages CPACK_SOURCE_TZ:BOOL=ON

//Enable to build ZIP source packages CPACK_SOURCE_ZIP:BOOL=OFF

//Cross compilation stage: either HOST(ie no crosscompile)|TOOLS|CROSS CROSS_BUILD_STAGE:STRING=HOST

//How many times to retry timed-out CTest submissions. CTEST_SUBMIT_RETRY_COUNT:STRING=3

//How long to wait between timed-out CTest submissions. CTEST_SUBMIT_RETRY_DELAY:STRING=5

//Path to a program. CVSCOMMAND:FILEPATH=CVSCOMMAND-NOTFOUND

//Options passed to the cvs update command. CVS_UPDATE_OPTIONS:STRING=-d -A -P

//Maximum time allowed before CTest will kill the test. DART_TESTING_TIMEOUT:STRING=1500

//Request to build project adios ENABLE_adios:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project boost ENABLE_boost:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project catalyst ENABLE_catalyst:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project cgns ENABLE_cgns:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project egl ENABLE_egl:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project ffmpeg ENABLE_ffmpeg:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project fontconfig ENABLE_fontconfig:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project freetype ENABLE_freetype:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project hdf5 ENABLE_hdf5:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project ispc ENABLE_ispc:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project libxml2 ENABLE_libxml2:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project manta ENABLE_manta:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project matplotlib ENABLE_matplotlib:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project mesa ENABLE_mesa:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project mpi ENABLE_mpi:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project mxml ENABLE_mxml:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project netcdf ENABLE_netcdf:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project numpy ENABLE_numpy:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project osmesa ENABLE_osmesa:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project ospray ENABLE_ospray:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project paraview ENABLE_paraview:BOOL=ON

//Request to build project paraviewsdk ENABLE_paraviewsdk:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project portfwd ENABLE_portfwd:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project pvospray ENABLE_pvospray:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project python ENABLE_python:BOOL=ON

//Request to build Qt4. Enable this to build the user interface // with Qt4. ENABLE_qt4:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build Qt5. Enable this to build the user interface // with Qt5. ENABLE_qt5:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project silo ENABLE_silo:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project szip ENABLE_szip:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project tbb ENABLE_tbb:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project visitbridge ENABLE_visitbridge:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project vortexfinder2 ENABLE_vortexfinder2:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project vrpn ENABLE_vrpn:BOOL=OFF

//Request to build project xdmf3 ENABLE_xdmf3:BOOL=OFF

//Path to a program. GITCOMMAND:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/git

//Git command line client GIT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/git

//Path to a program. HGCOMMAND:FILEPATH=HGCOMMAND-NOTFOUND

//Command to build the project MAKECOMMAND:STRING=/home/roger/cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake
--build . --config "${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE}" -- -i

//Path to the memory checking command, used for memory error detection. MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND:FILEPATH=MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND-NOTFOUND

//File that contains suppressions for the memory checker MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE:FILEPATH=

//Target ISA for OSPray (SSE, AVX, AVX2 or ALL). OSPRAY_BUILD_ISA:STRING=AVX

//Path to a program. P4COMMAND:FILEPATH=P4COMMAND-NOTFOUND

//String to use as a suffix for generated packages PACKAGE_SUFFIX:STRING=<default>

//Paraview's build mode PARAVIEW_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=

//Freeze Python packages/modules into the application. PARAVIEW_FREEZE_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF

//GIT_REPOSITORY for project 'paraview' PARAVIEW_GIT_REPOSITORY:STRING=https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview.git

//GIT_TAG for project 'paraview' PARAVIEW_GIT_TAG:STRING=master

//Rendering backend to use for ParaView PARAVIEW_RENDERING_BACKEND:STRING=OpenGL

//Specify the version number for the package being generated e.g. //
5.0.1 PARAVIEW_VERSION:STRING=5.0.1

//Pass LD_LIBRARY_PATH to build scripts. PASS_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_FOR_BUILDS:BOOL=ON

//Provide the list of Projects that ParaView should additionally // depends on PV_EXTERNAL_PROJECTS:STRING=

//Extra arguments to be passed to ParaView when configuring. PV_EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS:STRING=

//Number of make jobs to use for compiling ParaView itself PV_MAKE_NCPUS:STRING=5

//Path to a program. PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python2

//Path to a file. PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python2.7

//Path to a library. PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so

//Path to a library. PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND

//Value Computed by CMake ParaViewSuperBuild_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=/home/roger/paraview

//Value Computed by CMake ParaViewSuperBuild_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=/home/roger/ParaViewSuperbuild

//If enabled then the repository is fetched from git ParaView_FROM_GIT:BOOL=ON

//Which browser to use during testing, either chrome or firefox REMOTE_PVWEB_TEST_BROWSER:STRING=firefox

//A list of urls against which to run a simple Web Visualizer test. REMOTE_PVWEB_VISUALIZER_URLS:STRING=http://pvw-test.kitware.com/sbtest;http://pvw.kitware.com/sbtest;http://paraviewweb.kitware.com/sbtest

//Path to scp command, used by CTest for submitting results to // a Dart server SCPCOMMAND:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/scp

//Name of the computer/site where compile is being run SITE:STRING=roger-VirtualBox

//Path to the SLURM sbatch executable SLURM_SBATCH_COMMAND:FILEPATH=SLURM_SBATCH_COMMAND-NOTFOUND

//Path to the SLURM srun executable SLURM_SRUN_COMMAND:FILEPATH=SLURM_SRUN_COMMAND-NOTFOUND

//Suppress output for bzip2 SUPPRESS_bzip2_OUTPUT:BOOL=OFF

//Suppress output for paraview SUPPRESS_paraview_OUTPUT:BOOL=OFF

//Suppress output for png SUPPRESS_png_OUTPUT:BOOL=OFF

//Suppress output for python SUPPRESS_python_OUTPUT:BOOL=OFF

//Suppress output for zlib SUPPRESS_zlib_OUTPUT:BOOL=OFF

//Path to a program. SVNCOMMAND:FILEPATH=SVNCOMMAND-NOTFOUND

//When enabled, tests a live instance of ParaViewWeb. TEST_REMOTE_PARAVIEW_WEB:BOOL=OFF

//Trust SVN certificates automatically TRUST_SVN_CERTIFICATES_AUTOMATICALLY:BOOL=ON

//Enable the non-free parts of the superbuild USE_NONFREE_COMPONENTS:BOOL=OFF

//Use system bzip2 USE_SYSTEM_bzip2:BOOL=OFF

USE_SYSTEM_egl:BOOL=TRUE

//Use system png USE_SYSTEM_png:BOOL=OFF

//Use system python USE_SYSTEM_python:BOOL=OFF

//Use system zlib USE_SYSTEM_zlib:BOOL=OFF

//GIT_REPOSITORY for project 'vortexfinder2' VORTEXFINDER2_GIT_REPOSITORY:STRING=https://github.com/tjcorona/vortexfinder2.git

//GIT_TAG for project 'vortexfinder2' VORTEXFINDER2_GIT_TAG:STRING=master

//Location where source tar-balls are (to be) downloaded. download_location:PATH=/home/roger/paraview/downloads

//Extra arguments to be passed to Qt when configuring. qt_EXTRA_CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS:STRING=

//Work around a build issue in Qt. Use this if you see linker errors // with QtHelp and QCLucene. qt_WORK_AROUND_BROKEN_ASSISTANT_BUILD:BOOL=OFF


//MODIFIED property for variable: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS BUILD_SHARED_LIBS-MODIFIED:INTERNAL=ON //ADVANCED property for variable: BUNDLE_PREBUILT_MESA_BINARIES BUNDLE_PREBUILT_MESA_BINARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: BZRCOMMAND BZRCOMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //STRINGS property for variable: CATALYST_EDITION CATALYST_EDITION-STRINGS:INTERNAL=Essentials;Extras;Rendering-Base //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_AR CMAKE_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=/home/roger/paraview //Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3 //Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=5 //Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Path to CMake executable. CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/home/roger/cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake //Path to cpack program executable. CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/home/roger/cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cpack //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Path to ctest program executable. CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/home/roger/cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/ctest //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER CMAKE_C_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS CMAKE_C_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Path to cache edit program executable. CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/home/roger/cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/ccmake //Executable file format CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=ELF //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Name of external makefile project generator. CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL= //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Name of generator. CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Unix Makefiles //Name of generator platform. CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL= //Name of generator toolset. CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL= //Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this // project CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=/home/roger/ParaViewSuperbuild //MODIFIED property for variable: CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX-MODIFIED:INTERNAL=ON //Install .so files without execute permission. CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_NM CMAKE_NM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //number of local generators CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=2 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJCOPY CMAKE_OBJCOPY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJDUMP CMAKE_OBJDUMP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RANLIB CMAKE_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Path to CMake installation. CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=/home/roger/cmake-3.5.1-Linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.5 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STRIP CMAKE_STRIP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //uname command CMAKE_UNAME:INTERNAL=/bin/uname //ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: COVERAGE_COMMAND COVERAGE_COMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: COVERAGE_EXTRA_FLAGS COVERAGE_EXTRA_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_DEB CPACK_BINARY_DEB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_IFW CPACK_BINARY_IFW-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_NSIS CPACK_BINARY_NSIS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_RPM CPACK_BINARY_RPM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_STGZ CPACK_BINARY_STGZ-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_TBZ2 CPACK_BINARY_TBZ2-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_TGZ CPACK_BINARY_TGZ-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_TXZ CPACK_BINARY_TXZ-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_BINARY_TZ CPACK_BINARY_TZ-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_SOURCE_TBZ2 CPACK_SOURCE_TBZ2-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_SOURCE_TGZ CPACK_SOURCE_TGZ-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_SOURCE_TXZ CPACK_SOURCE_TXZ-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_SOURCE_TZ CPACK_SOURCE_TZ-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CPACK_SOURCE_ZIP CPACK_SOURCE_ZIP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //STRINGS property for variable: CROSS_BUILD_STAGE CROSS_BUILD_STAGE-STRINGS:INTERNAL=HOST;TOOLS;CROSS //ADVANCED property for variable: CTEST_SUBMIT_RETRY_COUNT CTEST_SUBMIT_RETRY_COUNT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CTEST_SUBMIT_RETRY_DELAY CTEST_SUBMIT_RETRY_DELAY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CVSCOMMAND CVSCOMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: CVS_UPDATE_OPTIONS CVS_UPDATE_OPTIONS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: DART_TESTING_TIMEOUT DART_TESTING_TIMEOUT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Request to build project bzip2 ENABLE_bzip2:INTERNAL=OFF //MODIFIED property for variable: ENABLE_paraview ENABLE_paraview-MODIFIED:INTERNAL=ON //Request to build project png ENABLE_png:INTERNAL=OFF //MODIFIED property for variable: ENABLE_python ENABLE_python-MODIFIED:INTERNAL=ON //Request to build project zlib ENABLE_zlib:INTERNAL=OFF //Details about finding PythonInterp FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_PythonInterp:INTERNAL=[/usr/bin/python2][v2.7.6(2.6)] //Details about finding PythonLibs FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_PythonLibs:INTERNAL=[/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so][/usr/include/python2.7][v2.7.6(2.6)] //ADVANCED property for variable: GITCOMMAND GITCOMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: GIT_EXECUTABLE GIT_EXECUTABLE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Result of TRY_COMPILE HAVE_VOID_PTR_SIZE:INTERNAL=TRUE //ADVANCED property for variable: HGCOMMAND HGCOMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: MAKECOMMAND MAKECOMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE MEMORYCHECK_SUPPRESSIONS_FILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: OSPRAY_BUILD_ISA OSPRAY_BUILD_ISA-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //STRINGS property for variable: OSPRAY_BUILD_ISA OSPRAY_BUILD_ISA-STRINGS:INTERNAL=SSE;AVX;AVX2;ALL //ADVANCED property for variable: P4COMMAND P4COMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PACKAGE_SUFFIX PACKAGE_SUFFIX-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PARAVIEW_BUILD_TYPE PARAVIEW_BUILD_TYPE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PARAVIEW_FREEZE_PYTHON PARAVIEW_FREEZE_PYTHON-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PARAVIEW_GIT_REPOSITORY PARAVIEW_GIT_REPOSITORY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PARAVIEW_GIT_TAG PARAVIEW_GIT_TAG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //STRINGS property for variable: PARAVIEW_RENDERING_BACKEND PARAVIEW_RENDERING_BACKEND-STRINGS:INTERNAL=OpenGL;OpenGL2 //ADVANCED property for variable: PARAVIEW_VERSION PARAVIEW_VERSION-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PASS_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_FOR_BUILDS PASS_LD_LIBRARY_PATH_FOR_BUILDS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PV_EXTERNAL_PROJECTS PV_EXTERNAL_PROJECTS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PV_EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS PV_EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PV_MAKE_NCPUS PV_MAKE_NCPUS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE PYTHON_EXECUTABLE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PYTHON_LIBRARY PYTHON_LIBRARY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: REMOTE_PVWEB_TEST_BROWSER REMOTE_PVWEB_TEST_BROWSER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: REMOTE_PVWEB_VISUALIZER_URLS REMOTE_PVWEB_VISUALIZER_URLS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SCPCOMMAND SCPCOMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SITE SITE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SLURM_SBATCH_COMMAND SLURM_SBATCH_COMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SLURM_SRUN_COMMAND SLURM_SRUN_COMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SUPPRESS_bzip2_OUTPUT SUPPRESS_bzip2_OUTPUT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SUPPRESS_paraview_OUTPUT SUPPRESS_paraview_OUTPUT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SUPPRESS_png_OUTPUT SUPPRESS_png_OUTPUT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SUPPRESS_python_OUTPUT SUPPRESS_python_OUTPUT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SUPPRESS_zlib_OUTPUT SUPPRESS_zlib_OUTPUT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: SVNCOMMAND SVNCOMMAND-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: TEST_REMOTE_PARAVIEW_WEB TEST_REMOTE_PARAVIEW_WEB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: TRUST_SVN_CERTIFICATES_AUTOMATICALLY TRUST_SVN_CERTIFICATES_AUTOMATICALLY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //ADVANCED property for variable: USE_NONFREE_COMPONENTS USE_NONFREE_COMPONENTS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1 //Use system adios USE_SYSTEM_adios:INTERNAL=OFF //Use system boost
```

Comment: This is no linking problem, the linker is something different. Can show us links to these sources? Adding a flag to CMake does not require them to be in the CMakeCache.txt. Search the documentation or maybe the source code.

Comment: I apologize for using the wrong terminology for my problem. I got the source from `git clone git://paraview.org/ParaViewSuperbuild.git`, also I tried using `cmake \src -DPYTHON_LYBRARY:FILE_PATH=\acanconda\lib\libpython2.7.so` but it says that the variable `PYTHON_LIBRARY` was not used by `CMAKE`

Comment: What's about `ENABLE_python`? Just to be sure, you have a separate build directory, right?

Comment: Yes I do have separate src and build folder. `Enable_Python` seems to enable [python scripting](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Python_Scripting) which is what I need (use Paraview within Anaconda-python2.7 environment)

Comment: Also I tried using `ccmake \src` and set `USE_SYSTEM_python:BOOL=ON` in the gui. Then I toggled advanced variables and set:
`PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python2`

`PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python2.7`
,
`PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`,
This is my default system python and is the same version of Anaconda (2.7 and with UCS4 support). I hope that after building the python modules will be compatible with my anaconda environment. Will report back after building.

Comment: It worked. Also, I do not know if it made any difference but I removed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from my bashrc temporarily to build  Paraview.

Comment: Great! If you think others will have similar problems, write an answer and accept it. Otherwise delete this question so nobody tries to help you further.

Comment: It seems that this issue will affect mostly people importing Paraview modules into Anaconda's Python in Linux systems because of the UCS discrepancy which is already a very small population (I think). However, Anaconda is gaining momentum in Academia and Industry and a bit of research indicates that Paraview and other VTK supported provided binaries present this issue. Therefore, even for my own sake I would like to leave my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background of the issue:**

The issue in the first place came after trying to use Paraview's pre-compiled binaries for Linux and importing `paraview.simple` into Anaconda's Python for Liunux. The provided binaries seem to be compiled with UCS2 support for Python, however, (as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762943/anaconda-vs-epd-enthought-vs-manual-installation-of-python/35484623#35484623) by @Dologan) Anaconda's Python for Linux was built with UCS4 support. Therefore, when importing `paraview.simple`, the error `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2*` potentially comes up.

**Solution**:

Building Paraview with UCS4 support for Python seemed the most reasonable way to solve this issue. However, to guarantee that built Python libraries support UCS4 you'll need to use system's Python when following the [superbuild](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Superbuild) instructions and make sure that indeed your system's Python does support UCS4. You can confirm this as follows in your console

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxunicode>65535
TRUE
```

If you see `FALSE` then you'll need to update your system's Python or build one that supports UCS4 and matches the Python version you need to use in your Anaconda environment. In ubuntu you can get Python2.7 with UCS4 support with `apt-get install python-dev`. After you confirm that `sys.maxunicode>65535` you can follow the Superbuild instructions which are quiet straightforward. I reccommend to remove temporally any definition of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in unix systems when configuring your build such that `cmake` picks up the right directories. Also, use `ccmake` gui and hit `c` every time you toggle or modify a new feature. For instance I started with `ENABLE_python` then `c`. Then `USE_SYSTEM_python:BOOL=ON` and `c` after again to make sure the Python related paths were set to the one I wanted to compile for. For ubuntu, those paths were

```
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python2
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python2.7
PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
```

Finally I was able to import the built `paraview.simple` module in Anaconda without further issues.